# Forward port over key-secured ssh connection

Tags: ssh

I run a personal web service on my desktop. On my laptop I use `ssh -L` to open a connection to it like so:

```
ssh -L <port>:<remote host>:<port>
```

That works just fine for Mac and Linux. How can I do the same thing on Android?

Comment: You use an [SSH Client](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sshclients#group_387). *JuiceSSH* is a very good one (which I'm using myself).